# using multi where when select items from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to selected items from mytable when using three tables and &_GET another id to open in this page so i want to use where and where to complete fetch my data by using two roles .

```
<?php   
$sel = "SELECT * FROM `informations` where `cate_id` =".$_GET['info_id'];
$done = mysql_query($sel);
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="location"></label>
<select name="location" id="location"><?php
$sel_cate = "SELECT * FROM locations";
$done_cate = mysql_query($sel_cate);

while($get_cate = mysql_fetch_array($done_cate)){

echo '<option value="'.$get_cate['id'].'">'.$get_cate['location'].'</option>';
$loc=$get_cate['id'];
}

?>      
</select>
<input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Go"> 
<input type="submit" name="all" id="all" value="Show All..."> 

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])){

$sel ='SELECT * FROM `pharmacies` WHERE `cate_id` ="'.$_GET['info_id'].'" ||     `location_id` = "'.$_POST['location'].'"';

?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like it shouldn't work ... what's the problem?

Comment: my problem is "i can't fetch my data when isset($_POST['go'])"

Comment: i can fetch my all data in the table but i can't filte it to fetch some data

Comment: `GET` and `POST` are usually not set at the same time .. should it be `$_POST['info_id']`?

Comment: i can see that but $_GET['info_id'] redirect from another page

Answer (score -1):

I tried this code and when isset($_POST['go']) variable $sel got $_GET['info_id'] and $_POST['location'] values. Query generated without errors, and must fetch information.

I not see mysql_query in your: if(isset($_POST['go'])). Maybe you forget query:

```
if(isset($_POST['go']))
{
  $sel = 'SELECT * FROM `pharmacies` WHERE `cate_id` ="'.addslashes($_GET['info_id']).'" or `location_id` = "'.addslashes($_POST['location']).'"';
  $selRslt = mysql_query($sel);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selRslt))
  {
    var_dump($row);
  }
}
```